# java: reading all csv files at once and sum over elements/rows

Tags: java, csv, sum

I have this function which is suppose to to open a file and read the first element [1st row][1st column], store it in a 3D array[file index][row][column], and open the next file and do the same process. This action should be running until all the rows and columns in all files are stored in the 3D array. 
My problem is that, this function do the job but it only reads the first line (row) of each file and stop there!!
Can any expert help me to figure out what is going on with my function? I have been working with java for about two month now :/

```
public static double[][][] fetch_data(int start, int end, int column) throws IOException{
    // start and end are for files start and end index. 
    int length = file_length(start); // since all files have the same length. The file_length() function just determine the length.
    data = new double [number_of_files][length][number_of_columns];
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        for (int index = start; index < end; index++){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file_call(index)))); // file_call() is a function that lookup the file dir.
            scan.nextLine();
                String scanedData = scan.nextLine();
                String [] array = scanedData.split(",");
                data[index][i][colum] = Double.parseDouble(array[index]);
                sum += data[index][i][colum];
                System.out.println(" element " + data[index][i][column]); // just to test the loop
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

The data files look like:
file (1):

```
A, B, C, D 
1, 2, 3, 4
13, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4
...
```

file (2):

```
A, B, C, D 
5, 6, 7, 8
55, 6, 7, 8
5, 6, 7, 8
...
```

file (3):

```
A, B, C, D 
9, 10, 11, 12
9, 10, 11, 12
91, 10, 11, 12
...
```

The expected output (we ignored the first line "A, B C, D" in the code above) :

```
1+5+9,  2+6+10, ...
13+55+9, 2+6+10, ...
1+5+91,  2+6+10,  ...
...
```

I hope to find someone expert in java who can teach me how to let me for loop to go through all the rows each file one step, like read first row in all files and come back again and read second row in all files and so on.

I will much much appreciate your help guys.

Best

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger to step through your code to find out what it is doing.

Comment: You should also turn off your computer and get a piece of paper and pencil. Write in words the steps to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did the debug, and that's how I found out it reads only the first line and stop.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I do, I actually have a large white board in my room and I do all the stuff on it.

Comment: I suggest you read about what `if` does.

Comment: The "if" condition was there by mistake and I removed it. It also has no role there, the outcome remain the same if you just think about it a bit!

Comment: exactly. The computer does exactly what you tell it to do. If you want to repeat something then you must say so.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a [loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_while_loop.htm):

```
if (scan.hasNext()){
```

Since you are recreating the Scanner each time, you are starting over at the top of the file each time. You have a few options. Either:

1. (inefficient) create a new Scanner for each iteration of each file, and skip to the correct line
2. maintain a list of Scanners and read all the files together
3. maintain a list of file contents and read each file sequentially

If you choose the option 3, you would need to process the results afterwards with another loop.

Comment: thanks, I actually find this "if" condition useless in my code, and I will delete it. But as you can see there are two main loops up there, and the third one is implemented outside the function. Or do you mean something else?!

Comment: @AhmedAbdelrahman if you click the word [loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_while_loop.htm) in my post, it will take you to a tutorial about the java while loop. Then you should consider how it might be useful in this position where you check hasNext()

Comment: Thanks Patrick again, the problem with the "while" condition that it will not stop until it read all the rows at once in one file and then move to the next file. While I want the output to be as shown, row per file. I struggled a lot with that until I switched to "for" loop which seems to do the job but with this bit of a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. Looks like I'm following approach (1) in my code above. Option (3) seems rather computationally expensive since I'm dealing with large data files. Option (2) is reasonable but can you please hit me with a hint how to maintain list of scanners? Do you have a tutorial for that? Thanks again.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelrahman in your code you already build a double[][][] of the required size. so how can you say that it is too much data? In addition, rustot has already provided you the code to fill the double[][][]. All that remains is for you to iterate through it.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, and also to rustot. I think I managed to solve my problem. I followed a completely different route, basically looked from a different angle and bingo, found the solution. I will post my solution here soon so as it might help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static double[][] getCsv(Path path) {
  try {
    return Files.lines(path).map(line -> 
      Arrays.stream(line.split(",")).mapToDouble(Double::valueOf).toArray()
    ).toArray(double[][]::new);
  } catch (IOException e) { 
    throw new UncheckedIOException(e); 
  }
}
```

...

```
Path[] paths = ...

double[][][] result = Arrays.stream(paths).map(
    path -> getCsv(path)
).toArray(double[][][]::new);
```

Comment: Thank you @rustot. This code is a bit beyond my level but I spend sometime to figure it out. In the method "getCsv" you are somehow mapping the String lines to double through "Files.lines(path).map(...)"  and then convert that into 2D array which later will be converted to 3D array through "result". First, I tried this code but seems there is something wrong with the method "getCsv" which I honestly don't know!! I also don't see how this will take line from each file and repeat that! Unless I'm looping over the file's index!!  But your help is appreciated though.

Comment: stream -> do something -> toArray() in this case just allow to allocate array at end of process, when actual size already known.

there 3 nested streams like 3 nested loops in your example. first stream of filenames, nested stream of lines from file and nested stream of numbers in line. each stream collapsed finally to array

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few wrong things here:

1. In the line `data[index][i][colum] = Double.parseDouble(array[index]);` the variable `colum` is not defined (misspelled?)
2. In the same line, `array[index]` is probably incorrect since you have to read all values from `array`, not just a single value. Also, `index` is the file index, not an index inside `array`. You should loop through `array` where `column` is the column index. i.e.:

   ```
   for (int column = 0; column < array.length; column++) {
       data[index][i][column] = Double.parseDouble(array[column]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, there are some parts unnecessary in your code. I would do it this way:

- initialize a double array (I do not know if size should be fixed or not - for now let's suppose it's fixed - you will extend it to be more general easily) with four columns and ten rows:

  `double[][] m = new double[10][4];`

It's an array of zeroes.

- now, suppose that `n` is number of files you want to read, so you read in an `for` loop (which will execute `n` times) all files, one after another. In `for` loop you use `while` loop with `hasNext()` method as a condition. Within `while` loop you read another lines, which you split into numbers and then add respective numbers to each cell in a row (you will need extra iterator to specify next rows).

Most of the operations on separate lines are done within the code you posted, so it shouldn't be a problem for you.

It's just an idea how to do it.

### Second approach

I can think of one approach without `while` loop. Consider using `Scanner` class, with `useDelimeter()` method you will split your file to separate lines, then split separate lines to numbers. You would need array `n` x `r` x `c`, where `n` is number of files, `r` number of rows, `c` number of columns. There you will store data from your files. Having that three-dimensional array you can easily add values in any way you want.

Comment: Oh man @Michal, you brought my nightmare back, the "while" loop! The main reason why I'm using "for" loop is because "while" loop takes the entire file, doesn't stop until it reach the last row in the file then move to the next file, which is something I really don't want.  In your comment "now, suppose that n is number ..." this is the common approach of reading any data file, I'm trying to override this approach by using the "for" loop.

Comment: Why reading whole file in `while` loop isn't an option? I don't see reason why you wouldn't do it? Especially, when number of rows differs from file to file, you can't read one line from all files, then second from all files, etc. Well, maybe you can, but can cause problems, which you wouldn't have when using while loop.

Comment: Sure you can, but with no while loop. That is the mean reason I switched to for loops. I managed to solve my problem and I'm posting my solution soon to help others who might need it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve my little problem by writing the following functions. 
The function below, go and read the first column in each file and treat it as the values stored for the x-axis. In this function we don't loop over the files index because the first column is the same for all files, so taking the first column from any file is sufficient. If you have your files are different then just loop over the file index as explain the second function below for the y-axis.

```
//================================= Generate x-data for x-axis
    public static double[][] get_x_data(int start, int end, int node) throws IOException{
        // start: for start file, end: for end file, node: for column
        // storing the volt column from the first file, we call it base experiment
        // base file is specified by the user or the machine will take the first file as base by default
        int base_index = 0; // should be implemented in the gui later

        if (base_index == 0){
            index = 1;
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            int length =  data_vault.file_length(index); // "file_length" is a function that determine the length of the file.
            String filename = data_vault.file_call(index); // "file_call" is a function that seek the name of the file from some directory. But you can insert you file directly here!
            data_x = new double [length][end];
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
            scan.nextLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
                String scanedData = scan.nextLine();
                String [] array = scanedData.split(",");
                data_x[i][index] = Double.parseDouble(array[0]);
                x_value = data_x[i][index]; // no need for this
                //System.out.println("x-axis " + data_x[i][index] + " file index " + index + " read " + i);
            }
        }
        return data_x;
    }
```

The function below seek each column independently and treat it as the y-axis values: it has an internal loop that runs through the rows of each file (i runs from zero to the last row, length, of the file). This 'i' loop is wrapped by another loop that runs over the files index (file_1, file_2, ..., file_n). Then all functions are wrapped by a loop that runs over columns. Below is the function that generate the y-axis entities:

```
//================================= Generate y-data for y-axis
public static double[][] get_y_data(int start, int end, int node) throws IOException{

    for (int index = start; index < end; index++){
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        int length =  data_vault.file_length(index);
        data_y = new double [length][end];
        String filename = data_vault.file_call(index);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
        scan.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            String scanedData = scan.nextLine();
            String [] array = scanedData.split(",");
            data_y[i][index] = Double.parseDouble(array[node]);
            y_value = data_y[i][index]; // no need for this
            //System.out.println(" y-axis " + y_value);
        }
    }
    return data_y;
}
```

Note 'index' here allows the user to choose where to start reading his files, starting from the first or the 'n' file. The index loop will just start from `'int start'` and loop over until `'int end'`.

Then you can basically do whatever you want with these matrices. I hope this solution will help someone.

Best for all of you.